# validator="" attribute of <h:inputtext> in jsf causing exception

Tags: jsf

We are trying to migrate from WS5 to WAS7 and the jsf code is causing the following error

Original Exception:

```
Error Message: JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /jsp/listView/listViewUPD_MAP_UM01.jsp: JSPG0301E: Invalid attribute, validator, for deferred method returning void. 
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: /jsp/listView/listViewUPD_MAP_UM01.jsp
Error Stack: 
com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslationException: JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /jsp/listView/listViewUPD_MAP_UM01.jsp: 
     JSPG0301E: Invalid attribute, validator, for deferred method returning void. 
     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.generator.BaseTagGenerator.evaluateAttribute(BaseTagGenerator.java:527)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you actually have a `validator` attribute without any value? I.e. `<h:inputText validator="" />` ? That's indeed invalid. If not, then please edit your question to include the related `<h:inputText>` tag and the associated validator method.

Answer (score 3):

Have similar problem, migrating from WAS6.1 to WAS7.0:

Exception:

```
com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslationException: JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /RegisterName.jsp:  
    JSPG0301E: Invalid attribute, validator, for deferred method returning void.
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.generator.BaseTagGenerator.evaluateAttribute(BaseTagGenerator.java:527)
```

RegisterName.jsp snippet:

```
<h:inputText
    id="callerName" 
    size="50"
    value="#{callerSC.currentCaller.name}"
    required="true" 
    validator="#{callerSC.validateCallerName}" 
    converter="StringTrimmer"
    onchange='return setFocusOn(this, "nextButton");'
>
        </h:inputText>
```

Got a tip to include the following snippet into my jsp pages

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral="false"%>
```

Worked for me, the exception went away

Alternative is to add following snippet into web.xml to specify el-ignored=false for JSPs

```
<jsp-config>                                                            
<jsp-property-group>                                                    
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>                                        
<el-ignored>false</el-ignored>                                          
</jsp-property-group>                                                   
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: Updating the web.xml, IMHO, is the way to go, as it addresses various potential problems across all JSP.

Answer (score 0):

We faced exact problem while moving from WebSphere 6.2 to WebSphere 8.5.5

`<%@ page isELIgnored="false" deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral="false"%>` works like charm.

But changing web.xml not working at least for WebSphere 8.5.5